# How do you coordinate server dependencies using chef?

Tags: chef-infra, configuration-management, knife

We've been using chef for our deployments, and it works wonderfully for straightforward scenarios. However, we now want to script out a redundant architecture on our VM infrastructure. Several boxes are clustered together, but running chef scripts prematurely will cause them to fail. For example, we would like to provision a Windows cluster. Server 1 can configure the Failover Cluster feature and then attempt to form the cluster, but since Server 2 is not yet configured, the run will fail.

How should this be done? Here are some ideas we've come up with:

1. Design the chef runs, knowing that they will fail but will eventually pass when continuously rerunning them.

   - This is not ideal from an automation standpoint since the feedback will become ambiguous. Did the run fail in an expected way, or did it fail for an unknown reason? This would likely require a human to get it set up.
2. Call "knife ssh" from a custom recipe to provision Server 2 when the recipe is run on Server 1. For example:

   ```
   windows_feature "FailoverClusters" do
       action: install
   end

   # ensure server 2 has the cluster feature enabled 
   # (this would likely be implemented as a LWRP using the  the Knife::Chef::Ssh class rather than the execute LWRP)
   execute 'knife ssh "name:Server2" "recipe[windows_cluster::secondary]"'
       action :run
   end

   # join the second server to this cluster (semi-pseudo code)
   windows_cluster 'server2' do
       action :join
   end
   ```
3. Alternatively, a coordinator script could be written so that it calls "knife
   ssh" in the correct order. The script would be ran from a build machine or a developer box:

   ```
   # ensure the failover cluster feature is enabled on the secondary server
   execute 'knife ssh "name:Server2" "recipe[windows_cluster::secondary]"'
       action :run
   end

   # install the failover cluster feature on the primary box and have it configure the cluster
   execute 'knife ssh "name:Server1" "recipe[windows_cluster::primary]"'
       action :run
   end
   ```
4. A different framework or technology that's already been developed to handle this issue?

Out of those solutions, we're leading toward 3 (or 4, if it exists). It seems like the cleanest way to organize the deployment in general, as the intent would live at a higher layer of abstraction.

What is the best practice or the common approach to handling these scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Chef Search for this.  Here is the logical workflow.

1. Run Chef on the first server, allowing the cookbook to set it as a "master" in it's chef node attributes
2. Run Chef on all other servers, allowing them to see the "master"

I call this a senior node deployment.  Where one server is deployed to first, then all others after.

The cookbook would have code that would search for the attribute, find or set it based on the results.  See below:

```
myclusternodes = search(:node, "cluster_name:clusterb")

if myclusternodes != nil
  master = myclusternodes.count == 0 ? node[:ipaddress] : myclusternodes[0].ipaddress
end

node.set[:clusterb][:master] = master
```